# NPE при поиске файла в ресурсах

Tags: java

Хочу воспроизвести wav из jar (но пока написать, код и чтобы он хотя бы воспроизвел в idea). 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
InputStream in =  this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("parser_uploaded.wav");
        try {
            AudioInputStream ain= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in); // ругается на эту строку
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Пробовал разные пути :

```
                       lib/src/main/resources/parser_uploaded.wav
                       src/main/resources/parser_uploaded.wav
                       resources/parser_uploaded.wav
```

Пробовал  и так писать.

```
  InputStream in =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("main/resources/parser_uploaded.wav");

Exception in thread "JNativeHook Dispatch Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:134)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
    at com.example.Main.PlaySound(Main.java:417)
    at com.example.Main.nativeKeyPressed(Main.java:344)
    at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$EventDispatchTask.processKeyEvent(GlobalScreen.java:561)
    at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$EventDispatchTask.run(GlobalScreen.java:521)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Класс, из которого пытаюсь получить, находится сразу по пути com/exemple

lib.gradle модуля

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.11.0'


}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

и вот проекта:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Попробовал поочередно в оба build.gradle добавить вот это: 
не работает. Ни каких папок ресурсов в jar нет и через idea NPE по прежнему.

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs "src/main/resources"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что ресурс у вас попадает в jar?

Comment: я уверен, что он туда не попадает. Но пока что пытаюсь воспроизвести проект в idea

Comment: судя по вашим комментариям, кажется, что способ получения файла и способ сборки файлов в jar как то связаны . И мне где то надо указать на мои ресурсы, а вот где если проект собран gradle

Comment: По идее gradle должен автоматом помещать такой ресурс внутрь jar (но все выглядит так, будто его там нет). Можете открыть результирующий jar любым архиватором, поддерживающим zip, и подтвердить, что этого файла в корне там нет?

Comment: Ну я же написал. ЕГо там нет. Я искал через Winrar.

Comment: Я делаю jar со всеми зависимостями. Но ресурсы почему то в jar не попадают в самом jar хаос из-за подключенных библиотек. И файл манифеста всегда неверный, мне приходится вручную в нем указывать на Main класс, хотя при сборке я указываю какой класс основной. НУ в общем всё сводится к тому, что в build.gragle надо что то писать, чтобы jar собрался как надо.

Comment: Попробуйте в открытую прописать необходимую директорию в sourceSets.main, как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982006/2908793). Если сработает - оформите, пожалуйста, ответом.

Comment: Просто я не понимаю, как связано отсутствие файла в jar с запуском программы через idea?  в idea в ресурсах ведь файл лежит. и если так то всё норм : audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("lib/src/main/resources/parserUploaded.wav"));

Comment: etki, добавил в конец вопроса. Не выходит что то . не знаю правильно ли я сделал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и заметил etki, проблема была где-то в сборке проекта. Сам проект у меня был очень некорректный. Решил не заморачиваться с поиском конкретной проблемы, а просто создал новый и запустил сборку через Gradle. И файлы появились в конечном jar и находятся корректно. Единственное, что не понял, почему они оказались в корне jar, а не в какой нибудь папке resources. Думаю, об этом надо сообщить gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно работать. Путь нужно указывать относительно папки `resources`.

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("parser_uploaded.wav");
```

Comment: не работает. та же ошибка

Comment: Запустите сборку пакета и посмотрите есть ли ваш ресурс в собраном пакете и по какому пути.

Comment: зачем, если я воспроизвожу код из idea ? до сборки еще дело не дошло . и да в сборке моих файлов нет и как туда их добавить не знаю. видел что надо с pom.xml какие то манипуляции проводить, но я вообще собирал посредством gradle

Comment: Покажи свой `build.gradle`

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `FileInputStream`.

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new FIle("res/sound.wav"));
```

Comment: это будет читать файл снаружи jar, и к конечному пользователю он так не попадет

Comment: @etki оу, точно, не прочитал эту часть вопроса

Comment: Да, если скормить File()   в    getAudioInputStream(), всё работает у меня. воспроизводит. но собираюсь из jar.